# ひとつ (give something a try)

Tags: grammar, meaning

Could you please explain to me how to use ひとつ (to give something a try) and give me some example sentences?

I have found ひとつ as a grammar pattern in this site:

https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n1-grammar-%E3%81%B2%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A4-hitotsu/

but the examples don't seem clear to me.

If you could help me, I would be really thankful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The examples in the link seem good to me overall. 明鏡国語辞典 defines this as follows:

> #### ひとつ
>
> 《副》
> ① 何かを思い立ったときに軽い調子でいう語。ちょっと。ためしに。「━やってみよう」

It's an adverb used before a verb related to (casual) attempting or suggesting, and it implies the result is not very predictable or the speaker is not very serious. Perhaps "anyway" is closest, but sometimes it's closer to "okay", "you know what" or "what about ～".

It also works as a casual "please":

> ② 相手に依頼するときに軽い調子でいう語。どうか。「━よろしくお願いします」

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. Then, can you always use ひとつ in any sentence with ~てみる、~ましょう or ~てください?

Comment: @Rick Basically yes, but it would sound frivolous if overused.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks a lot! :)