# What does 「やっぱり申告制でひとつ」mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, translation, phrases

Context: MC is asking 2 of his subordinates about their desired salary/ allowance, which he will pay for them. Since he has been isekai'd , he doesn't know about the average salary/ income or terminologies of this world(similar to Japan Sengoku era).
MC also just received a few territories from his clan leader as a reward, so he can use the income/taxes from those lands to pay for his troops / squad members.

> MC「幾ら欲しい？」
>
> Koroko「えっ」
>
> Hiyoko「何がですか？」
>
> MC「いや、扶持のこと。希望額があるかなって」
>
> Hiyoko「な、何なんですかその生々しい質問！」
>
> MC「だって俺、そういう相場も分かんないしさ。今までひよはどのくらいもらってたの？」
>
> Hiyoko「え、いや、その……」
>
> MC「ああ……そうか。雑司からだと格上げになるから、お給金もそのぶん上げないといけないのか……」
>
> だとすると、今のひよの収入も参考にならないよな。
>
> ……やっぱり俺じゃ分かんないぞ、こりゃ。
>
> Hiyoko「あの、その……」
>
> MC「**やっぱり申告制でひとつ**」
>
> Hiyoko「うぅ……どうしよう、ころちゃん」
>
> Koroko「どうしようって言われても……私こそ、どうしようだよぅ」

Comment: Does this help: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/80689/9831